# Can't enter in Ubuntu because fstab error

Tags: ubuntu, login, fstab

When I shut-down or restart the machine (VM) it won't log in to the system. I get the following error and then, continuous black-screen.

[image: Error]

This is my fstab, I don't know why uid=1000 is wrong. 
User with uid=1000 is the first user I've created when I installed Ubuntu. Its username is "laura".

```
   # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=9097fce3-f6e5-4708-9460-f40cf134d868 /               ext4   auto,rw,nosuid,errors=remount-ro 0       1
    # /backup was on /dev/sda4 during installation
    UUID=a7f3aa62-0c91-491d-b2c6-237c6376f526 /backup         ext4    auto,rw,uid=1000,noexec,defaults        0       2
    # /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
    UUID=2892df69-b043-4087-bfe9-dc8acd17bfc5 /home           ext4    auto,rwdefaults        0       2
    # swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
    UUID=7cf3a7d1-f9a3-484c-8a34-2ccd5df333d4 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem to be mounted on `/backup` is declared of type `ext4`. There is no [mount option `uid=` for Ext4 filesystems](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man5/ext4.5.html).

- Either the filesystem is not Ext4, and in this case the 3rd field of the `fstab` entry needs to be changed to reflect the correct filesystem type, or
- The option `uid=` needs to be removed.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I didn't know about that. I will change the owner and permissions of the file system (/backup) then.

Comment: @Sandrituky: You are welcome.

Comment: You could also put the s back so it reads suid. So that it sets user id to 1000 like it most likely was in the begining.